# Wordpress - template hierarchy for custom page not working

Tags: php, wordpress, html, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm building a `Wordpress` site using `html5blank` as a parent theme for the first time. I have my main pages set up and working using `page-slug.php` naming convention and all works fine. A couple of these pages require sub-pages but for some reason I cannot get these to work. Example -

On of my main pages is titled 'Agency' and within the agency page I have a number of images which act as links to a number (7) of sub-pages -

[image: Agency - sub page]

I've set the first image up with the correct link and page parent/child as so -

**page-agency.php**

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="twelve columns agencyproducts">
         <p>WHAT PRODUCT ARE YOU INTERESTED IN?</p>
         <a href="http://localhost:8888/agency/2k4k-production/"><figure>
         <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/production.png" alt="Production">
         <figcaption>2K / 4K PRODUCTION</figcaption>
                    </figure></a>
```

I've saved the sub-page file as `page-agency-2k4kproduction.php` in the theme file like the other pages. When I click on the link I get the `page.php` file showing with my header and form templates but not the sub-page code. Here's what I have in the `page.php` -

**page.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
       <?php get_template_part('form'); ?>

<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

In my `2k4kproduction.php` file I have this -

**page-agency-2k4kproduction.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <!-- custom code -->

           <?php get_template_part('form'); ?>


    <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Am I missing some steps in the hierarchy process?

I can't figure out why the main pages all work seamlessly but the sub-pages don't. I'v tried other permitations - `page-2k4kproduction.php`, `2k4kproduction.php`, `page-8.php` and they don't work either.

Do I have to save sub-page files in a different file to the main page file?

Does the page order in in the admin make a difference? FWIW I've placed the sub page as next in line to the last main page (8) rather than start a new number order for sub pages.

Really stumped on this one, I'm sure its something quite obvious but I just can't spot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress template hierarchy works perfect with `page-$slug.php` i don't know what could be the reason may be `2k4kproduction` slug issue.

it's better to use `page-template` instead `page-slug` workaround because if the slug change it won't show your page. go through [**this**](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/) tutorial for custom page template.

**`template-2k4kproduction.php`**

```
<?php /* Template Name: 2k4k Production */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<!-- custom code -->
<?php get_template_part('form'); ?>
<!-- custom code -->

<?php the_content(); ?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

[image: Page attributes with custom template]

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead it could be but i would suggest you to go with template options instead slug.

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead haha friend please my name is NOMAN not Norman :D xD